# How do we refer to a field when method argument has same name?

Tags: c++, this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Integer {
public:
    int val;
    Integer(int val = 0) {
        this->val = val;
    }
    void setVal(int val) {
        this->val = val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int val;
    Integer i;
    i.setVal(8);
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

When I execute my code I got `0`.I am new to C++,I do not understand `this`. Can someone elaborate more regarding this issues?

Comment: why not use a search engine for an explanation of this in C++?

Comment: C++ isn't java, so you should not just jump in and use getters/setters everywhere. `const` references eliminate almost all nead for getters and setters. Anyway, [they're evil](http://typicalprogrammer.com/doing-it-wrong-getters-and-setters/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're outputting the wrong `val`. As written, you could call `i.val` since you made the data member `val` **public**, but you could also choose to create a function (a "getter") for the Integer class. In any case, I recommend learning about **private** data members and how they can be used.

The getter approach would look something like

```
// in the class
int getVal() {
  return val; // equal to return this->val
}

// in main()
cout << i.getVal() << endl;
```

Note that if you change the main function you're not using your previous `val` in `main()` anymore. That's also the point - you're now using the class data member instead!

For a discussion on how one can get around the need to use the this pointer like you asked, check out this question: [Is using underscore suffix for members beneficial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630412/is-using-underscore-suffix-for-members-beneficial)

It also seems that you don't need to include *fstream* at this point.

Comment: Ok,works fine with i.val .Why should I introduce function?

Comment: @RichardRublev It generally improves encapsulation, which is a way of saying that you as a programmer will be in more control of your data. If you don't want users of your function to be able to change your variable without using the "setVal" function for example, the variable needs to be private. Read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm

Comment: @RichardRublev IMHO you do not need to introduce function  , the "getters" and "setters" are cargo cult junk

Comment: @MattMcNabb I kind of agree, but I think it's still worthwhile to learn about the concepts given that OP is new to C++.

Comment: Yes but without the "you should do this, you should do that" added on top.

Answer (score 1):

You invented a relationship between the `val` in `main` and the `val` inside the object `i`.

They have no relationship other than sharing a name.

- remove the unset `val` in `main`;
- output `i.val` instead.